# Are Strong Name and guid the same?

Tags: .net, guid, strongname

As per my knowledge, Strong Name uniquely identifies the assembly.
It is the combination of assembly name, version, culture, public key and digital signature. And when adding the assembly to GAC, we need to sign the assembly with a strong name.

If I am not wrong GUID is used as the ID when the assembly is exposed to COM.

I found that Strong name and GUID are similar in some sites. Are they reallly similar? If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUID ([globally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)) is a far more general term, used for many things in many different contexts. Although a GUID is indeed used to identify a COM component, a strong name has more information than that, as you've already said.

So no, they're not the same at all. They both have an aspect of identification, and they're both used as identifiers within .NET, but that's about all they have in common IMO.

Answer (score 1):

**Strong Name :**
Strong name is to identify the assembly in the GAC. When we think to put assembly in GAC instead of project folder,we have to give unique name to the assembly which contains assembly name, version etc. Because in GAC we can have more than 1 assembly with the same name bt they will differ in their version

**GUID**
Possessing a unique identifier makes it easy to store andretrieve information. This is especially useful when working with a databasebecause a GUID makes an excellent primary key.